# Firemonkey: can we update targetSdkVersion in AndroidManifest.template.xml?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I read that berlin is compatible with marshmallow, but i see that by default in the AndroidManifest.template.xml we have :

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="%minSdkVersion%" android:targetSdkVersion="%targetSdkVersion%" />
```

i don't know where delphi took the variable to update %targetSdkVersion% but it's seam to be all the time 14 and i don't see any way to configure it

i would like to replace %targetSdkVersion% by 23 (marshmallow api level, to support the app permissions), but is it safe to do so or it's will introduce many other bug ?

Comment: Do you have the proper SDK installed on your machine? Make sure Berlin is aware (Tools->Environment Options->SDK Manager), and then set the target for your project to the desired SDK using the Project Manager. The IDE will update the AndroidManifest file.

Comment: Or you could, you know, [read the documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Adding_an_Android_SDK). :-) Make sure you see step #4.

Comment: yes i do but it's not do anything with the AndroidManifest file. targetSdkVersion is still set to 14 :(

Comment: Then you didn't make sure you saw step #4. :-)

Comment: Also, did you set the proper SDK API-Level location (SDK Manager, SDK tab, last entry). The default on my system is 22.

Comment: yes i do everything correctly, update all path, and set SDK API-Level location to 23 but nothing change, in AndroidManifest file. targetSdkVersion is still set to 14. i think this also depend of the NDK (that we can not change by the way, else nothing work)

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with the NDK. It has to do with the SDK. If you set the target correctly, it works fine. Repeating that you're doing everything correctly isn't useful; you're clearly **not**, or it would be working. Again, you could read the documentation on [Customizing your AndroidManifest.xml file](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Preparing_an_Android_Application_for_Deployment), too. (It's really helpful when you're trying to figure out something to look in the help file.)

Comment: Ken, can you look in you delphi, as you have SDK to 22, if in any compiled AndroidManifest file of any of you android app. you will see that targetSdkVersion = 14 or 22 ?

Comment: I've pointed you to the documentation, which answers your question. Yes, you can update the targetSDKversion in AndroidManifest.template.xml, either for your specific project or for all future projects. What more do you need?

Comment: thanks Ken, no i just want to know from where delphi take the value of %targetSdkVersion% :)

Comment: @ken-white: "then set the target for your project to the desired SDK using the Project Manager. The IDE will update the AndroidManifest file." -> It will? I've really not been able to find out how to get the IDE to comply in this regard. Please advise. I am always keen to learn new tricks.

Comment: @long: Apparently, I'm in error. Thanks for letting me know. The info regarding editing the XML is valid, however.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

FireMonkey was developed to work against a certain range of Android functionality. As you can see from [the RAD Studio Platform Status page](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/PlatformStatus/en/Main_Page) FireMonkey apps built with Delphi 10.1 Berlin have a lowest supported Android version of 4.0.3, which corresponds to Android API Level 15.

The [`minSdkVersion`](https://d.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#min) field is supposed to be set to the earliest Android version your apps will work with so in truth this should probably be set to 15 but actually is set to 14 (Android 4.0-4.0.2).

If you look back at an Android manifest file generated by Delphi XE7, which supported Android 2.3.3 (API Level 10) it specifies a min SDK version of 9 (Android 2.3-2.3.2), which is the version of Android that introduced the [`NativeActivity`](https://d.android.com/reference/android/app/NativeActivity.html) type underlying every Delphi FireMonkey Android app. Again, this seems a little bit out of kilter with what is documented as lowest supported version.

Anyway, `minSdkVersion` can be used by Google Play store to filter your app out of the listings for someone running a lower version of Android. It is also checked when you install an app on a device; Android won't let you install on a lower version of Android.

[`targetSdkVersion`](https://d.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#target), on the other hand, indicates what version of Android your app has been tested with and works sensibly with. It can often be higher than `minSdkVersion` if your your app needs to use features introduced in Android versions later than `minSdkVersion`.

If you want to use a feature from API Level 23 then sure, you'll need to update that manifest part. Just remove the `%targetSdkVersion%` template from the Android manifest template file and replace it with the required version.

Problems that you might run into:

1. You'll *either* need to check the Android version and, if lower than your `targetSdkVersion`, not use those features that aren't available *or* set `minSdkVersion` to a suitably higher version to ensure the app can only run on devices that have the features you wish to use.
2. FireMonkey code not aware of differing behaviour in API Levels may
   function adversely. In your case you may get issues because of the
   different runtime permissions behaviour enabled in API Level 23.

Actually I can't currently think of any more issues, though a good amount of testing is recommended. You might have more to think about in a regular Android app using visual activities and so on, when different API levels may affect the theming or other UI elements. You can see the various things that change when you target target SDK versions on [this Android documentation page](https://d.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html).

By the way, the use of the SDK Manager in the Tools. Options... dialog is entirely irrelevant to the question of how to update the value in the generated manifest file. The only evident way to change it is to manually edit the Android manifest template file [as per the documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Preparing_an_Android_Application_for_Deployment), and mentioned in a comment.

The only relevance of the SDK Manager is that the default Android SDK installation for Delphi 10.1 Berlin installs the Platform libraries for API Level 22. If you want to use a feature from API Level 23 you might think that updating those platform libraries might be necessary, but of course if you're doing the coding in Delphi then you're (presumably) actually just compiling against import definitions of the features in that higher API level, and so whether or not those features are contained in the android.jar file is of no consequence.**

** I'm happy to be proved wrong on this count, but I have never observed a connection between the manifest and what the SDK Manager is set up against.

Comment: You clearly are more knowledgeable in this area than I am, so I'll take your word that my comment was wrong. Nice answer.

Comment: Thanks blong, definitively you are an expert in this domain :) i try to set targetSdkVersion to 23, but you are right firemonkey is not yet ready for the new permissions of marshmallow and it's crash (TlocationSensor for exemple crash when you enable it). it's not crash for everything, right now just on TlocationSensor i saw it, i open a bug report. for now i will stay on API 15 :(

Comment: The documentation you reference says that placeholders in the AndroidManifest.template.xml file are replaced by values from the Project Options. Is %targetSdkVersion% one of them? If so, where in the Project Options do you set it? I would rather do that than replace the placeholder with a hard-coded SDK version, as that may get overwritten by the next RAD Studio patch.

Comment: `%targetSdkVersion%` is not one of them, I'm afraid. This one is substituted to a hardcoded value, which I think is 29 in 10.4.x and 28 in the previous version