# targetSdkVersion for Android 26 using Delphi 10.1

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.1-berlin

I'm using Delphi 10.1 for developing android application and recently I got a mail from Google that I need have the Minimum target version a 26 and currently I have the basic configuration for Android 14 and how I can I change the Minimum target version to 26? This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39772269/firemonkey-can-we-update-targetsdkversion-in-androidmanifest-template-xml) explains the description about android configuration but it was not explained about Minimum target was changed was not explained. Please help me out.

Comment: According to Jim McKeeth from Embarcadero you just need to update the Android version and it works fine (https://twitter.com/JimMcKeeth/status/1024938872822747136)

Comment: As per the link you gave, Minimum SDK and Target SDK are 2 completely different things. It is the targetSdkVersion value that you need to change to (at least) 26 *if* you are deploying your app to the Google Play store. Unfortunately there are a number of side-effects of doing so, which I discuss here: http://delphiworlds.com/2018/05/targeting-android-8-and-higher/

Comment: @Dave Really? Jim said it was simple.

Comment: It’s certainly not as simple as just changing the targetSdkVersion, so I’m not sure what Jim was thinking there. It’s also possible that Push Notifications will not work as expected without further changes; I’m still looking into that

Comment: There are SOME things that are easy to solve by simply incrementing the `targetSdkVersion` to 26, but because of changes in API behaviors and security requirements, TRUE support for API 26 from Embarcadero will NOT be *fully* realized in 10.2, but in the upcoming 10.3

Comment: I have followed the link which you have mentioned and changed the targer version and minimum version to 28 but when I' trying to install .pk file in my mobile I'm getting **there was a problem in parsing the package** and I'm using Delphi 10.1. Now I'm trying to download Delphi 10.2.1 in another system and check.

Comment: Sorry. I have changed only TargerVersionnumber to 28 and now it was working fine and in default, all the permissions are disabled. How I can promote the user to enable. Please share any links. I'm using Contacts and Storage Permission,