# How to send SMS with C++ Builder in Android

Tags: android, c++, c++builder-2010

While searching the internet I came across the topic of sending SMS but unfortunately I did not find any example for C ++ Builder. Everything is written in Delphi. I tried to rewrite the instructions in C ++ and got this code:

```
#include <Androidapi.Helpers.hpp>
#include <Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes.hpp>
#include <Androidapi.JNI.Telephony.hpp>
#include <Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText.hpp>
#include <Androidapi.JNI.App.hpp>
#include <Androidapi.JNI.Net.hpp>

JString* wiadomosc = StringToJString( L"Wiadomość" );
Jnet_Uri* URI;
JString* destAdress;

 URI = StrToJURI( "12345678" ); // phone number
 _di_JIntent Intent = TJIntent::JavaClass->init( TJIntent::JavaClass->ACTION_VIEW, URI );  //ACTION_VIEW  ACTION_SEND
 Intent->setType( StringToJString("text/plain") );
 //Intent->putExtra( TJIntent::JavaClass->EXTRA_TEXT, wiadomosc ); StringToJString('sms_body')
 Intent->putExtra( StringToJString("sms_body"), wiadomosc );

 ::SharedActivityContext()->startActivity( Intent );
 //SharedActivity()->startActivity(Intent);
```

The program works but not as I've expected. The application selection window appears, and despite permanent SMS set as default I can not send sms without typing a phone number and text message even though that data is present in the code. Please give me a hint how to send sms without using the default program on Android.

Comment: I think you're going to have a hard time finding help for this-  C++ builder is a tiny fragment of users already, those using it for Android is tinier still (I've been doing Android for 7 years, this is the first I've ever even heard of it).  You're more likely to find help if you use straight NDK.  But I can tell you the NDK/Java way is to use SMSManager.  Using intents like you do will always launch the default app.

Comment: Can you post a link to the Delphi code to compare? I haven't used C++ Builder in years, but I'll always have a soft spot for it!

Comment: I tried also do it by this way: `JSmsManager* smsManager;
  JString* smsTo;

 // smsManager = JSmsManager::JavaClass->getDefault;

  smsTo = StringToJString("12345678");
  smsManager->sendTextMessage(smsTo, NULL, StringToJString("The message content"), NULL, NULL);` but there is error: "Exception class Segmentation fault (11), rhs->AddRef();"

Comment: @BareMetalCoder https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39762688/delphi-fmx-android-app-how-to-open-sms-window

Comment: @JacekRogowski: in C++Builder, you have to use Delphi-style interface wrapper classes for Delphi-style interfaces, not raw interface pointers, eg: `_di_JSmsManager smsManager = TJSmsManager::JavaClass->getDefault(); _di_JString smsTo = StringToJString(L"12345678"); smsManager->sendTextMessage(smsTo, nullptr, StringToJString(L"The message content"), nullptr, nullptr);`

Comment: @JacekRogowski: or, in your original example: `_di_JString wiadomosc = StringToJString(L"Wiadomość"); _di_Jnet_Uri URI = StrToJUR(L"12345678"); _di_JIntent Intent = TJIntent::JavaClass->init(TJIntent::JavaClass->ACTION_VIEW, URI); Intent->setType(StringToJString(L"text/plain")); Intent->putExtra(StringToJString(L"sms_body"), wiadomosc); SharedActivityContext()->startActivity(Intent);`